# javascript regroup an array of colors to specific number of colors

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, colors

I am trying to reduce an array / number of colors to a specific number by creating an average of each/some near colors. (in javascript)

I have an array of colors:

```
"000000,"Color01"
"8d6137,"Color02"
"ebc197,"Color03"
"ae733f,"Color04"
"935524,"Color05"
"ebc193,"Color06"
"320d06,"Color07"
"3f0f00,"Color08"
"724b35,"Color09"
"6d402c,"Color10"
"1c0800,"Color11"
"925829,"Color12"
"522b13,"Color13"
"7f4a2d,"Color14"
"603719,"Color15"
"e56a17,"Color16"
"8c331e,"Color17"
"110501,"Color18"
"674713,"Color19"
```

I need to get a new array of lets say 15 or 10 colors by replacing some of the nearest colors to new ones(If i have 8 colors, reduce to 4 colors)...
In an other way the script will select each (most close) 2 colors and create 1 (average)color and do this until get to the required/final number of colors.

Comment: Nope that makes no sense. Could you please give sample input  / output

Comment: It is very hard to understand what you want. Add an example output it would be much easier to understand the question.

Comment: Convert the hex value to either a HSL value (or integer value) then do the comparison and compression on these values. This codepen function will give you an idea of the values https://codepen.io/pankajparashar/pen/oFzIg

Comment: This is doable but I think you underestimate the work that needs to be done to find the two closest points in an array of 3D points

Comment: I believe they are wanting to get rid of close colors to allow for most contrasting colors. For instance, if you had 3 colors (red, pink, black) they want pink to disappear to leave red and black rather than to be left with red and pink. So in their example they have 19 color wanting 10. They don't want 10 reddish colors...they want a rainbow and getting rid of middle shades.

Comment: Matt you are right !

Comment: but the pefect result for me is : red, pink and black ----> (something in between /average red and pink  ~ maybe some kind of orange) + black

Comment: Sebastian Speitel you are also right ! but i hope this can be done